# How to set autosize font in zedgraph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I'm using ZedGraph in my c# project.

My X axis has text labels (used for bar chart), but with the default setting of `XAxis.Scale.IsPreventLabelOverlap = true` every second label is missing. When I change it to `false` with `XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 1` every label is shown, but font size remains the same, and labels overlap.

Is there any way to change font size of labels ? or preferably switch it to autosize ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgotten about this question long ago.
I've found my own solution, which isn't so clean. I've rewritten the `PaneBase.CalcScaleFactor()` method by changing `return scaleFactor;` to something like `return scaleFactor * 0.75f;`. Now it works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to let you know but as far as I know you cannot change the axis label font size directly. You can change the axis title font size, but not the labels themselves. You can change whether or not they autosize though and scale at which they autosize and it seems that is sort of what you want and that may end up helping you. [This](http://zedgraph.dariowiz.com/index08a1.html?title=How_does_the_font_and_chart_element_scaling_logic_work%3F) is the resource at which I was looking.

Set the `PaneBase.IsFontsScaled` property to true and then you can change the scale factor by using the `PaneBase.ScaleFactor()` method. Look through that resource I linked and I think you will be able to get it done. I don't have ZedGraph installed so I can't test it but I'm sure it will be something like that.

Good luck!

Comment: I forgot to answer this question. Project which used ZedGraph is long behind me. I haven't found any other solution than messing with `PaneBase.CalcScaleFactor()` method (you probably changed name of the method in your answer). Anyway, plus for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

my solution is ;

curve.Label.FontSpec = zg1.GraphPane.Legend.FontSpec.Clone();

curve.Label.FontSpec.Size = 6;